# Correct way to import non-less files in less-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, less-rails

I have been trying to `import` a normal css file in a less file as described in the [`less-rails`'](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails) documentation using [asset helpers](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails), e.g.:

```less
@import asset-url('some/path/to/something.css')
```

without any luck. The output does not change `asset-url(...)` to `url(/assets/...)`. And using [Sprockets' require directive](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) does not result in the correct order of importing dependencies, since it loads the assets before all other assets loaded using less `@import`.

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

I use `rails` 3.2 with `less-rails` 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to set asset-url or prepend your css with asset. less rails should be able to find your css with just simple import.